# React-native slow on android 5.1.1 but great on old 5.1

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

We have developed a react-native (v0.17.0) application for both iOS and Android. The iOS version is very responsive on physical devices. On Android devices I see a tremendous amount of variability. On Android version 5.1 the app is super responsive. On two separate phones with 5.1.1 (and both phones with much better specs) it is highly unresponsive. The navigation takes at least five seconds, TouchableHighlight buttons sometimes do not register at all. I have of course turned off dev mode but the issue still persists. My issue is that I can't see the degrade in performance on the emulator and this makes it hard to pin down the issue. Has anybody experienced and fixed a similar issue? What would be an advisable way to pinpoint the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling dev mode should help on android because it is super slow.

Comment: "I have of course turned off dev mode but the issue still persists."

Answer (score 0):

There are a little lack of details about what you are using or doing in your app. But i also had some performance issues in the app and could find the reasons for those by using the sysTrace wich is explained in the following link

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-ui-performance.html

Maybe you can take advantage out of this.